# What is the exact purpose of value attribute for an HTML button element?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button

What is the exact purpose of the value attribute for an HTML button element?
Is its use only limited to cases involving form submit?
Can you give one example where the use of value attribute is absolutely necessary?

Comment: You may have a look at https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element

Comment: or more readable here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_value.asp

Comment: The value attribute specifies the value of an <input> element.                                The value attribute is used differently for different input types:

For "button", "reset", and "submit" - it defines the text on the button,
For "text", "password", and "hidden" - it defines the initial (default) value of the input field,
For "checkbox", "radio", "image" - it defines the value associated with the input (this is also the value that is sent on submit)

Answer (score 1):

You can have two buttons with same name to submit different values.

```
    <form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  Choose your favorite subject:
  <button name="subject" type="submit" value="fav_HTML">HTML</button>
  <button name="subject" type="submit" value="fav_CSS">CSS</button>
</form>
```

Like: subject=fav_HTML

Comment: how are you suppose to distinguish these values on the server?

Comment: As you have two different buttons with the submit type, only one pair name-value will be sent as soon as you press the button. So you don't differentiate on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass value via event.target.value to a function for example.

```
myfunction(event){
    console.log(event.target.value);
}

<button value="foo" onclick={myfunction}></button>
```